# How to fix "undefined index" notice elegantly?

Tags: php, validation, php-7

This is probably a generic question and 99% of the solutions I've read is to just use `isset` to be safe and verbose. However, I still think it's not that elegant and also a bit repetitive.

To understand my question a bit better, here's a general pattern on my code:

```
  public static function buildObject(array $userProperties) {
    // Here, I'm building a user from an associative array.
    // If the developer passes in an array with missing name or address,
    // this will generate an undefined index notice!

    $user = new User();
    $user->setName($userProperties['name']);
    $user->setAddress($userProperties['address']);
    return $user;
  }
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Adding in `isset()` checks on all set calls. This might not be a bad idea for this example, but I have some huge classes with a lot of properties and it looks and feels very repetitive.
2. Making the array safe by looping over properties and setting them to null if they're not present in the array. This doesn't seem that bad in code but feels like a workaround.
3. Using null coalesce operator `?? null`. This also feels repetitive and not that readable.

I'd prefer a simple solution that would not add much logic but will look elegant. I know it's preferable to have validation in here, but I'll encounter the same problem when handling optional fields.

Comment: the error would occur on $userProperties['name'] though? the moment I try to access undefined index 'name' on $userProperties

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking once inside the set function, doh! Comment gone!  I will keep an eye out on this question.  I did some research, there does not seem to be a "best" solution, and what you propose seems to be what others do.

Comment: Don't you need to validate that certain data is passed in as a minimum?  Optional fields can be set to some dummy value (possibly NULL), but things like a name should be set and setting a user without one should have some form of error.

Comment: Unless you pass in a model object with the user properties set as parameters so you can do `$obj->getName() or $obj->getAddress()`, I don't think there's any other way you're going to be able to bypass checking the array with `isset()`, at a minimum, to make sure the key exists before getting it's value.  I think you're overthinking trying to optimize the code. This is about as basic as it gets in any professional code I've ever seen.  The only way this gets simpler is if the PHP preprocessor itself is modifed by Zend to set null defaults when an array element is invoked and unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no objective metric for *elegance*. What one developer may find elegant other will find verbose and repetitive. Whatever is considered *best* for something like this will be always entirely subjective.

That being said, if you find yourself doing something unnecessarily repetitive and verbose over and over, it is usually a smell that something could be improved upon.

The possible solutions for your use case will vary a lot depending on which direction you want to go. You may create a parameter object that implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), so that consumers can still treat the parameter as an array but you are able to use it more succinctly in your method.

Or you could create a builder object with a fluent interface so that creating a user doesn't require an array at all:

```
 $user = UserBuilder::start()
             ->setName('Foo')
             ->setLastName('Bar')
             ->build();
```

But it all depends on the specifics of your implementation, on the additional work you are willing to go through for this relative convenience, and what's specifically what you want to solve.

A very common and very simplistic pattern when passing associative arrays as parameters and you want to have some guaranteed keys accessible; is to use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

E.g.:

```
function foo(array $arguments) {
    $arguments = array_merge( [
             'name'     => null,
             'lastName' => null,
             'role'     => ROLE_USER
           ],
           $arguments);
}
```

No amount of magic will give a name to a `User` object that hasn't received one, but this way at least the array keys are set, and you can use this to set other default values before working with them.

In the end, **you** will have to decide what works for you, what's do you consider elegant, and what kind of implementation is really worthwhile in your project.